# Determine interval of convergence and the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine interval of convergence and the sum:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+3}
$$

any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that for $x=1$ the series $\sum_n \frac1{n+3}$ is divergent then the radius of convergence $R\le1$ but for $x=-1$ the series $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{n+3}$ is convergent by Leibniz theorem so $R\ge1$. Conclude.

For the sum we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+3}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{x^{n-3}}{n}=\frac1{x^3}\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n}=\frac1{x^3}\left(-\log(1-x)-\sum_{n=1}^2 \frac{x^{n}}{n}\right)
$$

Comment: says its [-1,1); 1/3 if x=0,
-1/x^3 ln(1-x) - 1/x^2 - 1/2x ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(x)$ your sum.

On its domain:
$$
\frac d{dx}x^3S(x) =\frac d{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+3}}{n+3}
\\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+2} = \frac {1}{1-x} - 1 - x
$$
So the radius is $R=  1$ [it is invariant under derivation and multiplication by $x^3$] and then you integrate and divide by $x^3$.

Comment: this makes no sense? Im trying to find the sum and interval of convergence :DD